# Package rn-fetch-blob contains invalid configuration: "dependency.hooks" is not allowed

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, dependencies, rn-fetch-blob

Package rn-fetch-blob contains invalid configuration: "dependency.hooks" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.

package.json -
"react-native": "0.69.2",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"

Answer (score 11):

Just go to the rn-fetch-blob package folder from node_modules and delete react-native.config.js file.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed with a PR that has been submitted to NPM and merged in here: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/pull/796#issuecomment-1199721977).

This should be fixed in the upcoming update, but in the meanwhile, you can do the following to solve it:

```
npm add rn-fetch-blob@0.13.0-beta.2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the rn-fetch-blob package folder from node_modules and delete react-native.config.js file.

it worked